# Capturing dates of a particular format from raw data

Tags: regex, pandas

I'm trying to capture dates of the form -

20 Apr 2009

20 April 2009

20 Apr. 2009

20 April, 2009

...from raw text in a pandas dataframe. I want to get rid of rest of the text apart from the dates

I'm been partially successful in my attempt

```
df['some_column'] = df['some_column'].str.replace(r'(.*?)(\d{1,2}[ ](?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*\.?,?[ ]\d{4})(.*?)\n', lambda x: x.groups()[1])
```

But for some cases I'm getting the preceding/succedding text as well ..
Any inputs would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `\n\1`, you only match the lines that are followed with the same text as captured in Group 1.

You may use:

```
df['some_column'] = df['some_column'].str.replace(r'(?s).*?(\d{1,2} (?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*\.?,? \d{4}).*', r'\1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QaOR6j/1)

Note that you need no lambda expression as the replacement argrument, the `\1` replacement backreference puts back the text captured into Group 1.

Alternatively, use `str.extract`:

```
df['some_column'] = df['some_column'].str.extract(r'(\d{1,2} (?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*\.?,? \d{4})', expand=False)
```

**Details**

- `(?s)` - `re.DOTALL` modifier (in case there are line breaks)
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(\d{1,2} (?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*\.?,? \d{4})` - Group 1: one or two digits, space, month abbreviation  followed with 0+ lowercase letters, an optional `.`, `,`, then a space and four digits
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

Comment: My bad , the \1 at the end wasn't a part of the expression ... but the (?s) solved it .